# How Can I Find and Add Numbers from a String in One Cell

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help with adding the numeric values in an alphanumeric cell?

For example,

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
'Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

' Initialise return string to empty                       '
retval = ""

' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
'   return string.                                        '
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
        retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
    End If
Next

' Then return the return string.                          '
onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Results:

```
Dim myStr as String myStr = onlyDigits ("3d1fgd4g1dg5d9gdg") MsgBox (myStr)
```

314159 gives a sum of 23!

Comment: If you want to add the digits, why have you declared `retval` and the function return values as `string`? Using `string + string` always produces a string. If you want a number, you need a number to start with in the first place.

Comment: I can see from your comment at @PatricK's answer that you have changed the requirements of your question. Please make sure that you also amend your original post, so that the community can vote properly, and those who search for a similar problem check quickly if this question of help to them or not. I am going to delete my answer as it does not meet your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
Function SumOnlyDigits(s As String) As Long
    Dim Total As Long, i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then Total = Total + CLng(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next

    SumOnlyDigits = Total
End Function
```

Changed to return the total as Long instead of String.

UPDATE:
This will sum consecutive numbers mixed inside alphabets

```
Private Function SumOnlyNumbers(s As String) As Long
    Dim Total As Long, i As Long, x As Long

    i = 1
    Do Until i > Len(s)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
            x = CLng(GetNumber(Mid(s, i)))
            Total = Total + x
            i = i + Len(CStr(x))
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    SumOnlyNumbers = Total
End Function

Private Function GetNumber(s As String) As String
    Dim sTmp As String, i As Long

    sTmp = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        ' Join characters until non numeric
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
            sTmp = sTmp & Mid(s, i, 1)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetNumber = sTmp
End Function
```

Comment: The SumOnlyDigits function works!!!  Would it be to complicated to account for double digit addition.  For example, -1hour -3hours -10hours.  The above script will calculate 4.  I want it to calculate 13.  I would be great to see the 10 as ten instead of 1.

Comment: Have created 2 functions to accommodate sum of consecutive numbers. One to spot numberic, one to retrieve consecutive numbers as string.